# How to insert a CLOB using OleDb

Tags: c++, oracle, oledb

Could someone post some sample code showing how to insert text greater than 4000 characters in length into an Oracle 10g CLOB field?
I am using the Oracle OLEDB provider and ATL in C++.
My naive attempt returns the error 'ORA-01704: string literal too long' whenever the text I am attempting to insert goes over 4000 characters in length.
I'm guessing I need to parameterise the 4000+ character string somehow but I'm not sure how to do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got this working.
In case anyone else has the same problem, I inserted the value EMPTY_CLOB() then used the ISequentialStream interface to stream the text into the empty field.
The Microsoft mydyntext sample shows how to do this.